# Why isn't my project rendering anything? It just shows a checked pattern

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, export, error

I've been working on this project for a few weeks and the rendering has been working fine up until now. The render preview is working, as you can see in the screenshot at the top of the attached image, but when I hit fnF12 to render, it just shows the checked box pattern and doesn't do anything, as you can see in the screenshot at the bottom of the attached image. Why has it stopped working suddenly and what can I do? I tried opening up another project and rendered the default cube, and it worked fine, so the issue must be specific to this project. Any help much appreciated, I'm pretty much a beginner at Blender. Thank you!
[image: Screenshots of issue]

Comment: Look carefully when you go to render. Are there any banners or messages that pop up, warning you of any errors? It may be that you hit the limit for your computer's memory. Try switching to CPU render.